# Multiple instances of flowplayer (flash video) does not play sound in IE7

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-7, flowplayer

I got page which has multiple instances of flowplayer (all but one hidden at any one time).

It works fine on all browsers except (obviously) IE7, for which first 32 instances of the flash player work fine, however starting with 33rd instance of the video player I am not getting any sound (just visuals).

I am completely lost at this one - does IE have a limit of how many sound channels it can support? Or destroy and recreate video flash objects with javascript?

Any ideas?